# tkinter optionmenu close event

Tags: python, events, tkinter, optionmenu

I am trying to display a tooltip for optionmenu items in tkinter. I have figured out how to do that. The problem I am left with is closing the tooltip (toplevel) window. I want to do so when the user selects an option or clicks outside the optionmenu (which closes the menu of the option menu). The enter and leave events don't seem to be doing the trick. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I have added some code on what I have tried. The "test" print occurs whenever I hover over menu item 1 (which is what I want) but I want to fire enter and leave events whenever the user opens or closes the menu as a whole. I tried binding them to the optionmenu but it is unreliable and sometimes triggers leave events when it shouldn't.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, BOTH, Menu, Label, SUNKEN, X, BOTTOM
import tkinter as tk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background = "white")
        self.parent = parent
        vals = ["1","2","3"]
        var = tk.StringVar()
        var.set("1")
        option = tk.OptionMenu(root,var,*vals)
        option.pack()
        t = option.children["menu"]
        tk.Menu
        #Do I need to unbind
        #t.bind("<<MenuSelect>>", self.test_func)
        t.bind("<<MenuSelect>>", self.test_func)
        t.bind("<Enter>",self.enter_func)
        t.bind("<Leave>",self.leave_func)

    def test_func(self,event = None):
        if self.parent.call(event.widget,"index","active") == 0:
            print("test")

    def enter_func(self,event=None):
        print("entered")

    def leave_func(self,event=None):
        print("left")
root = tk.Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

One way I have found to close the tooltip (not shown in example) is to trace the variable associated with the optionmenu and when it changes kill the topwindow. However, if the user opens the menu, hovers over options, then clicks outside the menu items, the topwindow tooltip stays because the menu item never changed.

The question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416431/tkinter-on-popup-menu-close-event) one

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of the code you have and what you have tried with the Enter and Leave events?

Comment: I added some more information!